# How do I modify a VS Build Workflow if VS can't find any custom DLLs it uses?

Tags: tfs, workflow, tfsbuild

I'm using TFS Server 2010.

In my source I have a folder called `BuildProcessTemplates`. This has a child folder called `Custom Assemblies`.

Now, when the build runs, it happily loads the DLLs in the `Custom Assemblies` folder and does its thing.

I need to modify the .xaml file that defines the workflow of the build. If I double click on the .xaml file VS tries to open it but throws an error saying it can't find certain types that I know are defined in the DLL that is in the `Custom Assemblies` folder.

The workflow is told where to find these types when the build runs by Build Controller as it is defined as a property in the TFS Admin Console.

So, how on earth do I get VS to open my .xaml file properly? How do I let it know where to look for the DLL? I've tried moving all of the files in `Custom Assemblies` in to the same folder as the .xaml file, but that didn't help.

Clearly I'm missing something; I just don't have a clue what it might be.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2012, although I've tried accessing the workflow.xaml file in both 2012 and 2010 with the same result.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but there is a bug in TFS 2010 that causes problems with opening the xaml files. Check out this blog post for details and workaround: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/07/17/tfs-2012-cleaning-up-workflow-xaml-files-aka-removing-versioned-namespaces.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally create a C# Project (Unit Test is easiest because it is pretty bare). 
When you have you project you then need to:

- Add the XAML as a File,
- Add the Custom Activities DLL's as references.
- Add the relevant TeamFoundation* references from the GAC (make sure the TFS version matches - 2010 = v10, 2012 = v11).

Also, I always open our TFS "Build Project" with VS version that matches our TFS Version, I find it keeps the number of problems down.

There's a great series of posts from Ewald Hofman [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx), that go through the process - I find it a bit dated, and that the [Wrox Professional TFS 2012](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00B2S48B6/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B00B2S48B6&linkCode=as2&tag=taeguk-21) book does a better job of explaining it, if you can get a copy.

Comment: This looks like its getting me much closer. I have made a new c# unit test project, added me xaml file - set the build properties to x86 and now its throwing an error about Invalid markup - because its missing references etc as you mention. How do I add the custom activities dll's as references....and how do I add the teamfoundation references from GAC - I think this is mostly what I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: You right click on the project and add references, the tfs ones you can find by searching for TeamFoundation. Click browse to add the custom ones