# Team Foundation Server 2012 Express BuildTemplate process xaml files not opening

Tags: c#, xaml, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I have Visual Studio 2013 Express version:12.0.21005.1REL with Team Foundation Server 2012 express installed.

I need to alter a Build Process xaml file however when I download from source control and open the file this happens:

[image: design view]

The machine I am using is a 64bit system running a 64 bit windows 7 - but I am very surprised this should happen. How exactly do I go about altering this build process when the design view is not operable and the xml is horridly difficult to read / alter. Are there any resources which can help me?

Or is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: What is the configuration your current project is compiling under? The designer only supports loading X86 binaries. This means that when you are working in a solution/project that's configured for X64 or ARM the designer won't load correctly.

Comment: This is what I meant in the comment on the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894190/how-do-i-modify-a-vs-build-workflow-if-vs-cant-find-any-custom-dlls-it-uses/23899727#23899727

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is opening the xaml in split view to enable the visual designer to work. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763100(v=vs.110).aspx) explains how to set VS to open xaml files in full text mode.

***EDIT***

I'm sorry, I misunderstood what you wanted to do. Seems this is a bug that has been reported with a possible workaround mentioned [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730526/design-view-is-unavailable-for-x64-and-arm-target-platforms-because-the-document-contains-custom-elements) and a relevant SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378919/visual-studio-designer-in-x64-doesnt-work).

Comment: I want it to open in the visual designer...but it doesnt!